# If $f$ is the angle of an analytic function $\varphi(s)$, is $f$ continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is as follows: Let $\varphi(s)=\rho(s)\exp(if(s))$ be an analytic function, so that $f$ is the angle of an analytic function $\varphi(s)$. Here $f$ is a real valued function. The question is: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Well, consider $f(z) = \lvert z\rvert$. It's continuous, but not analytic.

Comment: Consider the function $f(z)=\overline z$.

Comment: In fact, no non-constant function from $\Bbb{C}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ is analytic.

Comment: Here $ϕ(s)=ρ(s)exp(if(s))$, $f$ is the angle of an analytic function $ϕ(s)$

Comment: What do you mean as an analytic function?

Comment: The question was edited, making the previous comments irrelevant. The answer is still no, though. Example: $\phi(s)=s$ with $\rho(s)=| s|$ and $f(s)=\mbox{arg} (s)\in [0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @julien: There is no exception?

Comment: @Chaos A zero of $\varphi$ always gives rise to a point of discontinuity of $f$ (if $\varphi \not\equiv 0$), since in every neighbourhood of the zero, all angles are assumed. If $\varphi$ has no zeros, you may have a globally continuous angle $f$ (you do if the domain of $\varphi$ is simply connected).

Comment: @DanielFischer: This is the answer. The function $φ$ has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: Yes, there are nice cases. As indicated by Daniel, if $\phi$ does not vanish on a simply connected domain, you have an analytic antiderivative of $\frac{\phi'}{\phi}$ which yields in particular a continuous argument.

Comment: @julien: Thank you very much.